# Code issues, struggling to understand where i'm going wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

def main_account_screen():

    main_screen = Tk()  # create a GUI window
    main_screen.geometry("700x450")  # set the configuration of GUI window
    main_screen.wm_iconbitmap('py.ico')
    main_screen.title("Account Login")  # set the title of GUI window

    # create a Form label
    Label(text="Login or Register", bg="red", width="300", height="2", font=("Arial Black", 13,)).pack()
    Label(text="").pack()

    # create Login Button
    Button(text="Login", height="4", width="30", font=("Arial Black", 13,)).pack()
    Label(text="").pack()

    # create a register button
    Button(text="Register", height="4", width="30", font=("Arial Black", 13,)).pack()

    main_screen.mainloop()  # start the GUI

main_account_screen()  # call the main_account_screen() function


def register():
        # The Toplevel widget work pretty much like Frame,
        # but it is displayed in a separate, top-level window.
        # Such windows usually have title bars, borders, and other “window decorations”.
        # And in argument we have to pass global screen variable

    register_screen = Toplevel(main_screen)
    register_screen.title("Register")
    register_screen.geometry("300x250")

    # Set text variables
    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()

    # Set label for user's instruction
    Label(register_screen, text="Please enter details below", bg="blue").pack()
    Label(register_screen, text="").pack()

    # Set username label
    username_lable = Label(register_screen, text="Username * ")
    username_lable.pack()

    # Set username entry
    # The Entry widget is a standard Tkinter widget used to enter or display a single line of text.

    username_entry = Entry(register_screen, textvariable=username)
    username_entry.pack()

    # Set password label
    password_lable = Label(register_screen, text="Password * ")
    password_lable.pack()

    # Set password entry
    password_entry = Entry(register_screen, textvariable=password, show='*')
    password_entry.pack()

    Label(register_screen, text="").pack()

    # Set register button
    Button(register_screen, text="Register", width=10, height=1, bg="blue").pack()

    global main_screen

# add command=register in button widget

    Button(text="Register", height="2", width="30", command=register).pack()

    main_screen.mainloop()  # start the GUI

main_account_screen()  # call the main_account_screen() function
```

I'm struggling with the understanding of combining two features, that being the combination of the login screen and the actual registration post.

Just trying to get the code to work on a basic level but I'm struggling with my indentations and anything that helps tie the code together.

Comment: What exactly is throwing an error?

Comment: Button(text="Register", height="2", width="30", command=register).pack()
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: The comment causes your IDE to remove the indent - indent the comment back out and you'll be good.

This does in turn throw a different error, whereby you've declared `main_screen` as `global` AFTER using it - not allowed.

Comment: also when i globally declare main_screen, it says - SyntaxError: name 'main_screen' is used prior to global declaration

Comment: so do i not need to globally declare it?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/korey/PycharmProjects/carrental2019/login system.py", line 73, in <module>
    main_screen.mainloop()  # start the GUI
NameError: name 'main_screen' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1     -     so the program boots which is progress

Comment: There are a lot of things we need to fix in this code.

Comment: all help is greatly appreciated :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You ever only need one instance of `Tk()` followed by one instance of `mainloop()`. You have mainloop in multiple section for no reason.
2. You are calling the function that build your root window twice. and this really should only be called at the bottom once.
3. You try to use global to get the root window however the function that made the root window does not declare it in the global namespace so this will not do anything useful.
4. You have a lot of superfluous comments. You do not need to comment `# create Login Button` That is obvious from the code. Comments should be reserved for clarification where it is needed. In some complex bit of code that is not obvious when reading. You code makes enough since on its own to not need most if not all of your comments.
5. the lines where you create your variables `username = StringVar()` are not going to do exactly what you think. Because you are not telling them to belong to the top level window like this `username = StringVar(register_screen)` Those variables will actually belong to the main instance of tk by default AKA your root window. This can cause problems and recently the last time I came across issues with this is due to threading. So make sure you always declare what owns that variable.
6. You do not need to assign your labels, buttons, or entries in this case unless you plan on changing them or updating them down the road. The reason that it is ok for the entry field in this case is due to the variable assignment. We can get values from that directly.
7. You do not need to add spacer labels. IE `Label(text="").pack()`. You can add padding to your pack statement and you can also use `grid()` as well with padding and that is my preferred method of handling widgets.

Lastly you should do `import tkinter as tk` instead of importing `*`. This will prevent any overwriting of methods and make it clear where you are getting your widgets/methods from.

Here is your code simplified. Let me know if you have any questions. I have reduced your 75 lines of code to 25 lines.

```
import tkinter as tk


def register():
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)
    top.title("Register")
    top.geometry("300x250")
    username = tk.StringVar(top)
    password = tk.StringVar(top)
    tk.Label(top, text="Please enter details below", bg="blue").pack()
    tk.Label(top, text="Username * ").pack()
    tk.Entry(top, textvariable=username).pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    tk.Label(top, text="Password * ").pack()
    tk.Entry(top, textvariable=password, show='*').pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    tk.Button(top, text="Register", width=10, height=1, bg="blue").pack()


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("700x450")
root.title("Account Login")
tk.Label(root, text="Login or Register", bg="red", width="300", height="2", font=("Arial Black", 13,)).pack()
tk.Button(root, text="Login", height="4", width="30", font=("Arial Black", 13,)).pack(padx=15, pady=15)
tk.Button(root, text="Register", height="4", width="30", font=("Arial Black", 13,), command=register).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help, it has helped my understanding much more and thanks for the code simplification, that is brilliant. Can't thank you enough